# Windows Portable Devices API and WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE command

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, camera, wpd

I am currently writing a C# windows forms application for a government agency that needs to collect a photograph of a person standing in front of a counter using a fixed camera. To collect the photograph the application is required to operate a still camera and retrieve the image.

The application will be run on Windows7 so WIA (Windows Image Aquisition) is not supported. I have written code using the Windows Portable Devices API to get a list of supported commands from the devices plugged into the computer.

For the application to take a photograph, the device plugged into the computer (camera) must support the `WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE`. Currently none of the cameras that I have access to (various Canon powershots) support the required `WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE` command and alot of internet searching has not revealed a list of cameras that support the `WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE` command. Most cameras support the Storage commands but not the ability to programmatically take a photograph via the Windows Portable Devices API.

Has anybody successfully taken and retrieved a photograph using the Windows Portable Devices API and WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE command?
If so what brand and model of camera did you use?

Answer (score 3):

WPD_COMMAND_STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE_INITIATE maps to the InitiateCapture (0x100E) PTP command.

This list has some PTP cameras that support InitiateCapture: http://www.circuitsathome.com/ptpusb-control-camera-data